# Laravel 5.2 S3 Upload Error

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5

I seem to be getting alot of errors trying to get and store things in s3 in Laravel.

This is my controller

```html
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
        $s3->get('index.html');
  
    }
```

I am getting a error. There was a index.html file in the bucket.

```
FatalErrorException in SignatureInterface.php line 2: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

If I run change it to this

```html
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
        $s3->put('index.html', 'test', 'public');
    }
```

I get this error

S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 192: Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/willjeweler?prefix=index.html%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Could this be a problem with my user on amazon? Some type of permission issue?

- I created the user and added the env for key and secret.
- I gave my user admin privilege.

Answer (score 1):

> `FatalErrorException in SignatureInterface.php line 2: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`

you can try to extend the limit. open your conf file under `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and add the following `xdebug.max_nesting_level=500`

> `AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

you need to download the file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and from your `php.ini` settings reference the new certificate as

```
curl.cainfo = "/home/ubuntu/config/cacert.pem"
```